# python celery json serializer with group

Tags: python, celery

Why the below snippest throw `EncodeError: keys must be a string` when using json serializer?

It works well with pickle serializer, but json serializer cannot do this simple workflow.

any idea or fix?

```
@task
def task1(msg):
    return msg + ' *'

sig = task1.s() | group(task1.s(), task1.s())
tsk = sig.apply_async(args=['text'])
print tsk.get()
```

expected result is like pickle serializer result as below:

```
[u'text * *', u'text * *']
```